# sql developer query result does not show non-english letters

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Im using sql developer 23.1 for oracle database.
My native language is Turkish which have some letters that does not exist in English language.
I guess somehow I have messed up with its format.
When I run query for retrieving customers name, for some characters the result tab displays square box with X in it.
the funny thing is that it does not act for all the foreign letters like this.
"Ö" letter is displayed as it is, however letter "Ş" is replaced with boxy thing.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the font, it's almost always the font.

[image]

Go into preferences, and on the Fonts page, put your sample text, characters into the preview window, and then cycle through the fonts until you're good.

Recent copies of SQL Developer default on the Hack font, which seems to treat your character just fine.

Comment: thanks a lot. but I think I have to need to go to help desk , because although I have chosen the font that solves the problem, I cannot save the settings, It reverts back to existing one.

Comment: tell them you need rights to read/write/save files in your OS user's AppData folder, under roaming profiles. That's where these settings are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely comes from character encoding settings in Oracle Database or SQL Developer.

1. Check Oracle Database's character set with this query:

   ```
   SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
   ```

   If the result isn't `AL32UTF8` or another set that includes Turkish characters, consider changing it.
2. Configure SQL Developer:

   - Go to 'Tools' -> 'Preferences'.
   - Navigate to 'Environment' -> 'Encoding'.
   - Set the encoding to 'UTF-8'.
   - Restart SQL Developer.

If both are correct, the issue may come from how data was entered into the database. You can verify the data by checking the raw bytes stored in the database using Oracle's `DUMP` function.

Comment: For #1, you may want `SELECT parameter, value FROM   nls_database_parameters WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` your query does not appear to work [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TgnlYSZn).

Comment: "SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'" didnt work for me. I can ran @fiddle query. the value for the parameter is WE8ISO sth. The thing is I asked my friend whose sql developer works fine, to run the nls_database_parameters query. His result is same as mine.